# How can I deal with unmapped spring configuration files in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

When dealing with this problem, I already understand that I need to do File -> Project Structure -> modules -> + -> and select spring. However what I don't understand is in what part of modules I need to have selected before I click +, and which spring option to choose. I don't see a singular Spring option, but instead Spring batch, Spring DM configuration, Spring MVC, and more. Should I choose one of these options? Or do I need to configure something so that I only see the Spring option.